# PHP return or continue on null

Tags: php

is it possible to write something like this in single line in PHP:

```
return $this->checkToken() ?? continue;
```

So it will return the value but if null is returned it will continue the program.
I know you can capture the value and then do if value !null return.

Was wondering if there is a single line version that could be used.

Answer (score 3):

Once you start an expression with `return`, you are committed to returning *something*.

What you can do instead is inline an assignment and check since the result of an assignment expression is the value assigned.

```php
if (($token = $this->checkToken()) !== null) return $token;
echo 'If $token is null, this line will execute';
```

That's about as *single-line* as you're going to get. For readability / maintainability, I'd still go with the following

```php
$token = $this->checkToken();
if ($token !== null) {
    return $token;
}
// and so on
```

Comment: yes, that's what I have atm. I thought there is maybe a more elegant way of writing it like in other languages :)